# How to add the values by key in Map

Tags: scala

Say I have a map like this:

```
val testMap =Map("Sita" -> 1,"Sita" -> 2,"Ram" -> 3,"Ram" -> 4,"Shyam" -> 5)
```

I want to have a output as:
`Map("Sita" -> 3,"Ram" -> 7,"Shyam" -> 5)`

Comment: `testMap`, as you've defined it, is not possible. Try `testMap.toString()` and see what you get.

Comment: There is some confusion over what you are actually asking, so can you please clarify the question. For example, where does the `7` come from?

Comment: @Tim I wanted to do the same using Map as i did it using List:                                                                                                                           
    val testList = List("Sita" -> 1, "Sita" -> 2, "Ram" -> 3, "Ram" -> 4, "Shyam" -> 5)
    val res = testList.groupBy(_._1).map(l => (l._1, l._2.map(_._2).reduce(_+_)))

    println(res)

Comment: Actually i got this question in the interview......that's why i asked @Tim

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first problem, as pointed out by @jwvh, is that this `Map` will only have 3 values because the keys cannot be duplicated. Earlier key/value pairs will be replaced by later key/value pairs with the same key.

To fix this, start with a `List` rather than a `Map`:

```
val testList = List("Sita" -> 1, "Sita" -> 2, "Ram" -> 3, "Ram" -> 4, "Shyam" -> 5)
```

Then you can use `groupBy` to collect the values with the same key, and then compute the sum of the grouped values:

```
testList.groupBy(_._1).map{ case (k, v) => k -> v.map(_._2).sum }
```

This will give you the `Map` that you are looking for.

Comment: I can't understand why this answer is downvoted... Can anyone explain it?

Comment: Hello, Thanks for the solution but i have already solved it the way you suggested above, but i want to solve it using Map only....

Comment: @DiwakarKumar There is no solution using only `Map`. As soon as you put the data in the `Map` in your first line of code you lose the information that you need to produce the result you want. This has already been pointed out to you by at least three people.

Answer (score 1):

Your map contains duplicate keys.

```
val testMap = Map("Sita" -> 1, "Sita" -> 2, "Ram" -> 3, "Ram" -> 4, "Shyam" -> 5)
```

**What happens when Map contains duplicate key is:**

If the map previously contained a mapping for the key, the old value is replaced by the specified value.

So,

```
"Sita" -> 1 will be replaced by "Sita" -> 2 and

"Ram" -> 3 will be replaced by "Ram" -> 4
```

Just print the `testMap` you will get:

```
Map(Sita -> 2, Ram -> 4, Shyam -> 5)
```

So, I don't think it can be done using single Map.